# ¿Por qué descargar imagenes desde FTP es mas lento que descargarlas de una base de datos con variables de tipo Blob?

Tags: java, jdbc, ftp

Les dejo el codigo de descarga de la base de datos y de FTP:

codigo base de datos:

```
productos=new ArrayList<Object[]>();
try {
    //System.out.println("antes de la consulta preparada");
    //PreparedStatement consultaPreparada=conexion.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM productos");
    Date segundos=new Date();
    Date segundos2;
    System.out.println("antes de llenar el resultset "+segundos.getSeconds());
    ResultSet resultado=statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM productos");

    Object[] campo;
    segundos2=new Date();
    System.out.println("antes de entrar al while total demora="+(segundos2.getSeconds()-segundos.getSeconds()));
    while(resultado.next()) {
        campo= new Object[numeroColumnas];
        campo[0]=resultado.getBlob(1);

        for(int i=2;i<=numeroColumnas;i++) {
            campo[i-1]=resultado.getString(i);
        }
        productos.add(campo);              
    }

    resultado.close();
    statement.close();

} catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Codigo FTP:

```
cliente.connect("hostname);
boolean login=cliente.login("usuario", "password");
cliente.enterLocalPassiveMode();
if(login) {
    cliente.setBufferSize(48576);
    cliente.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
    InputStream input=new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\julio\\Desktop\\imagen0.jpg"));
    boolean cambio=cliente.changeWorkingDirectory("/jvm/apache-tomcat-8.5.23/domains/juliogodoymunoz.cl/ROOT/");
    ArrayList<OutputStream> array=new ArrayList<OutputStream>();
    for(int i=1;i<17;i++) {
        String imagen="imagen"+i+".jpg";
        array.add(new BufferedOutputStream(newFileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\julio\\Desktop\\"+imagen)));
    }
    if(cambio) {
        //System.out.println("se cambio directorio");
    }else {
    //System.out.println("no cambio directorio");
    }
    try {
        //cliente.storeFile("imagenFTP.jpg", input);
        System.out.println("antes de retrieveFile()");
        for(int j=1;j<17;j++) {
            cliente.retrieveFile("foto"+j+".jpg",array.get(j-1));
            System.out.println("foto"+j);
            array.get(j-1).close();
        }
        System.out.println("salio del for");

    }catch(CopyStreamException e) {
    }catch(FTPConnectionClosedException e) {
    }

    input.close();
    System.out.println("salio");
    cliente.logout();
    cliente.disconnect();
}else {
    System.out.println("no se conecto al servidor");        
}

} catch (SocketException e) {       
    System.out.println("socket exception");
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("IOException");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Desde ya muy agradecido por sus respuestas, gracias.

Comment: ¿De cuántos ficheros estamos hablando? ¿De qué tamaño? ¿Cuáles son los tiempos que has calculado?

Comment: un poco mas de un segundo por imagen de extencion jpg con un tamaño que varia entre los 20 y 95 KB